# error when installing apk Q-municate

Tags: android, quickblox, q-municate

I have downloaded Quickblox Q-municate from the github,

https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android

I open the project with android studio and I successful generated apk but when i try to install it in my phone it's not working. A message appears: Installation error. I can not install
I want to understand what is happening.Please help

Comment: could you please provide us with the exact error message you get? a screenshot would be preferrable

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer
I can not do a snapshot. It is in my phone.Now icorrectly install it but 
When i launch the app, it's show this message : Sudden
sudden closure application q_municate (the process com.quicblox.q_municate) .try again

Answer (score 0):

U think its because you already have a vernsion downloaded from playStore ?
and then you try to install another version from Android studio as Debug apk.

- try delete the Q-municate from your phone, then try installing from android studio